# While loop within thread is causing program to block (C)

Tags: c, multithreading

The point of threads is to be able to run multiple blocks of code at once. The first thing I think of when this possibility comes into my head is having two infinite loops running at once. Before I tried to get this working with two threads, I tried to get it to work with one, with no success.

So I have a thread like this:

```
void *myThread(void *args) {
    sleep(0.1);
    while (1) {

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And I am creating the thread like so:

```
pthread_t thread_id;
printf("Before Thread\n");
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThread, args);
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
printf("After Thread\n");
```

When I run this, `"After Thread"` does not print! Why is this happening? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: you might want to look up asynchronous functions

Comment: @Brian no. i dont want an async func here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);` waits for the thread to finish. And a thread running a `while (1) {}` loop will never finish.

Comment: do I need the ```pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);``` line then? @MartinHeralecký

Comment: @MattX If you don't put it there, the _After Thread_ message will print immediately after starting the thread, which will keep running.

Comment: If you changed the code in `myThread` to loop 10 times and print something out or sleep and then return, you'd wait for it to finish with the call to `pthread_join` in main.  And after that your program could exit.  If you just leave `myThread` as it is and take out the call to `pthread_join`, your program won't wait for the thread to finish and exit right away.

Comment: @MattX Whether or not you need it depends on exactly what you're trying to do, which we do not know. What you should do depends on exactly what this thread is doing and how it relates to what the program as a whole is doing.